# Convex function not recognized as convex by ConvexOptimization

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am working with a convex function that I want to minimize, say $f(x) = x+\frac{1}{x-1}, ~x>1$. When I run `ConvexOptimization[x+1/(x-1),x>1,x]`, I receive the following error message:

```
ConvexOptimization::ctuc: The curvature (convexity or concavity) of the term 1/(-1+x)+x in the objective function 1/(-1+x)+x could not be determined.
```

I was wondering, is there a Mathematica function that can solve convex optimization programs, simply relying on the assumption that the program is convex without checking it? What I mean by this is `NMinimize` will work just fine but not assume the program is convex, and so perhaps, perform much more computation than required for what should be a simple gradient descent.

Comment: FWIW if we transform the input into a [posynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posynomial), `GeometricOptimization` can handle it: `GeometricOptimization[x + 1/x, x > 0, x] /. (x -> a_) :> (x -> a + 1)`

Comment: Right, the actual objective I have in mind is $f(x) = x + y^\top(x I_n - Q)^{-1} y$ where $y$ is a fixed vector, $Q$ fixed such that $I_n\succeq Q\succeq0$ and the constraint is $x>1$. Not sure whether this can be placed into any such routine.

Comment: @Cryme are you sure it's convex? That objective appears concave for some matrices -- https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-bumpy-resolvent.nb

Comment: @Cryme just try `Q = RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[100]]`, you get all sorts of shapes

Comment: Yes, it is smooth with $f''(x) = 2 y^\top (xI_n-Q)^{-3} y\geq0$. Don't forget that $Q$ is symmetric.

Comment: @Cryme I see....if it's convex in 1 variable, `FindMinimum` will find the solution using gradient descent. `ConvexOptimization` is meant for problems too difficult for gradient descent, but that requires the problem to have special form like Conic or SDP

Comment: I see thanks, if it's only a mere gradient descent that should be alright then. I'll see if I can speed it up for my specific problem.